# Parsing XML as NodeSeq, how to read the root element name?

Tags: xml, scala

When I read an XML file/string as a `NodeSeq`, how to get the name of the root element?

Seems kinda basic, but I don't see an immediately obvious way to do it, looking at [`NodeSeq` API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.0-M3/index.html#scala.xml.NodeSeq).

Minimal example:

Given arbitrary XML:

```
<HelloWorld>
    <Foo>Bar</Foo>
</HelloWorld>
```

And code that loads it as `NodeSeq`:

```
val xml: NodeSeq = XML.loadString(xmlString)
```

What is the simplest way to get the root element name, in this case `"HelloWorld"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the first `Node` using `head` or `headOption` and then get the name using `Node.label` :

```
import scala.xml.XML

val nodes = XML.loadString("""
  <HelloWorld>
    <Foo>Bar</Foo>
  </HelloWorld>
""")

val label = nodes.head.label // String: HelloWorld
```

And as [Dylan pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34589688/parsing-xml-as-nodeseq-how-to-read-the-root-element-name/34590050?noredirect=1#comment56936628_34590050), `XML.loadString` actually returns an [`Elem`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.0-M2/index.html#scala.xml.Elem), so the simplest way to get root element name is:

```
XML.loadString(xmlString).label
```

Comment: Thanks! As well-formed XML documents always have a single root element, `foreach` looks a bit odd; I'd probably go with `val rootName = nodes.headOption.map(_.label).get`

Comment: If you are sure your XML document has a root element, you can do `nodes.head.label`. (`foreach` is just an easy way to execute a side effecting function on an `Option`)

Comment: XML.loadString() throws a SAXParseException if you pass a string which is not well-formed XML, so yes, I am sure. :) (Just tried it with empty string, arbitrary non-XML string, and XML string with several root nodes.) So turns out here `headoption` just complicates the code unnecessarily, and indeed `head.label` is the way to go. Can you update the answer?

Comment: `XML.loadString` returns an `Elem` (a subclass of NodeSeq), which has its own `label`. No need to go through a `head`

Comment: @Dylan: Thanks, good observation. That made me consider changing an internal API in the app I'm working on to accept Elem instead of NodeSeq everywhere, but then I realised one starting point for my XML handling (besides `XML.loadString`) is [Play's `request.body.asXml`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaXmlRequests) which gives `Option[NodeSeq]`. So I'd need to do a conversion there; not sure if it's worth it...

Comment: @Jonik fwiw it looks like that body parser eventually delegates back to the same `XML.load` method that returns an `Elem` - they just gave an explicit type signature of NodeSeq. Up to you what to do with that info.